# Include dependencies in Felix OSGi bundles

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm new to OSGi. I'm using Apache Felix. I have build a bundle, and that has a dependency. When I try to start the bundle with `start file:/path/to/bundle.jar` it gives me this error.

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve lk.ucsc.research.BellyRunner [20](R 20.0): missing requirement [lk.ucsc.research.BellyRunner [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=lk.ucsc.research.bellygraph) Unresolved requirements: [[lk.ucsc.research.BellyRunner [20](R 20.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=lk.ucsc.research.bellygraph)]

My Maven project structure is as follows,

```
|-Belly
  |-BellyGraph
  |-BellyRunner OSGi( dependencies: BellyGraph )
```

I tried adding `<Embed-Dependency>BellyGraph</Embed-Dependency>` too. But It didn't work. Please help me to get this run. The full POM could be found [here on Github](https://github.com/agentmilindu/NaturalGraphStreaming/blob/master/Belly/BellyRunner/pom.xml).

Answer (score 1):

The error simply says that your OSGi run configuration is missing a bundle that exports the `lk.ucsc.research.bellygraph` package. This package is needed by the BellyRunner bundle to resolve.

I think that start learning OSGi using maven is not a good idea as many important details and concepts simply get concealed by the "mvn install" magic. If I were in you, I would start from the OSGi enRoute tutorial: http://enroute.osgi.org/qs/050-start.html

After that you can explore how to do this in maven: http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_eval/050-start.html